# Install PHP MSSQL drivers in Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, php

How do I install MS SQL drivers for PHP on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for mssql directly under Ubuntu.  There are a couple options.

I believe you can get some functionality by using the sybase module.

php5-sybase

```
Package: php5-sybase
Priority: optional
Source: php5
Description: Sybase / MS SQL Server module for php5
 This package provides a module for Sybase and Microsoft SQL Server
 database connections directly from PHP scripts. It also includes the
 pdo_dblib module for use with the PHP Data Object extension.
```

Another option would be to access the server via odbc.  Install php5-odbc and tdsodbc.

The mssql extension that is part of PHP will only function when PHP is built on Windows.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php

There is another driver/extension from Microsoft that supports PHP, but appears to only be functional on Windows.  http://www.codeplex.com/SQLSRVPHP

Comment: Why Ubuntu does not ship with the MSSQL driver, you can compile it on linux. It uses the FreeTDS driver as opposed to the Sql Server 2000 native driver.

Comment: You should add your own answer with a description to how to do this, and links to the source.

Comment: Agreed, I will add a full answer when time permits. For now, look at the [requirements page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php) for proof that it works on linux.